# Efficient algorithm to search convex polygons in a 2D space

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a 2D Space in which there is a convex polygon (in this case the red square) and a large number of triangles. My goal is to select the triangles

- Belonging
- Intersecting
- Surrounding

the red square (For more clarity, the triangles I am searching for are the ones in black).

[image]

I am currently using a brute force approach by checking the listed conditions on each triangle.

Is there a more efficient algorithm or any kind of heuristic which can be applied to reduce the time complexity?

Comment: You can't reduce the theoretical time complexity, because in theory, all of the triangles could belong, intersect, or surround the square. The best you can do is quickly remove some triangles, for example if the maximum X value for any vertex of the triangle is less than the minimum X of the square, then that triangle can be ignored.

Comment: You can only change the time complexity if you have a fixed list of triangles, and a large list of squares that you want to compare with the triangles. In that case, you can use 2D space partitioning data structures like [quad trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), or 1D data structures like [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) to speed things up.

Comment: Possibly you should also clarify what colour this triangle should be.... https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSHNU.png

Comment: Do you have axis-aligned right triangles only?

Comment: @CiaPan It should be blue since it does not meet any of the listed conditions.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, no. Triangles are all of different shape and dimension.

Comment: @user3386109, Yes it could be an idea. Maybe to make the solution more flexible one could consider, for each triangle, the circle circumscribed to it. Then, a triangle is removed if the distance between the center of its circle and the center of the one circumscribed to the red square is greater than the sum of their radiuses. What do you think?

Comment: For simple polygons like triangles and rectangles, the math to compute the intersection probably takes about the same time as computing the circumcircles and checking the distance. The advantage of computing the intersection is that it always works, even for CiaPan's example. For that case, the intersection *must* be computed, because preliminary checks will indicate that the polygons might intersect (X and Y values overlap, and the circumcircles overlap). For higher order polygons, circumcircles might help, if you can compute the circle efficiently.

Comment: You want to reduce complexity in terms of what? The number of triangles? (Pretty much impossible, you need to read them all and that's O(N)). The number of red polygons? The number of sides in the red polygon(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Improve efficiency with a pre-filter**

As checking orthogonal coordinates are relatively easy (maybe via a [quad-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)), consider first a [bounding box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box) for each object.  Then easy to eliminate objects that could not possibly meet the search criteria.  The remaining objects can then use a more time intensive approach.

Comment: If there's only one square to check, or if the list of triangles is not constant, building the quad tree takes more time than just checking all of the triangles.

Comment: @user3386109 True, yet the data structure holding the objects is not defined.  I am suggesting to stored them a quadtree to begin with.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, Yes, that's a good idea. However, as suggested, it is useful only when the red squares to query are many, which is not the case.

Comment: @Francesco Its still useful for 1 red polygon if the polygons were already in a quad tree.  Since the question does not oblige a linear list of polygons, how the polygons should be stored is an open parameter in achieving _Efficient algorithm to search polygons in a 2D space_.

Answer (score 0):

From a comment of yours, I infer that preprocessing the triangles is not an option. So unless the triangles are known to enjoy some special property that can be exploited, you can't avoid an exhaustive comparison of all triangles to the polygon (using the separating axis theorem, among others).